# oracle occi getString gives _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, oracle

I am trying to do a `getString` on a `ResultSet` from a OCCI Oracle query but I always get the `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)` assertion.  My project is Multi-Threaded Debug and I have tried to set it to Single-Thread Debug, as I found suggested online, but that makes no difference.

I'm a bit at a loss what is causing this assertion to occur.  Can someone help?

It seems I only have it with the `getString()` function, not with any other.

```
    oracle::occi::Environment* environment;
    oracle::occi::Connection* con;
    oracle::occi::Statement* stmt;
    oracle::occi::ResultSet* res;


        try{
         environment = oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::DEFAULT);
         con = environment->createConnection("db", "pssw", "DATABASE");     

        std::cout << "created connection" << std::endl;

        std::stringstream query;

        query << "SELECT MOD_KEY, MOD_SCRIPTLANGUAGE, MOD_SOURCE, MOD_CODE, MOD_STYLE, MOD_TYPE ";
        query << "FROM DB.MEDICAL_OBS_DEF ";
        query << "WHERE MOD_KEY = 735";

         stmt = con->createStatement(query.str());
         res = stmt->executeQuery();

         res->setMaxColumnSize(3,100);

         std::cout << "executed query" << std::endl;
         std::string mystring;
         while (res->next())
         {

             /*mystring = */res->getString(3);  ///_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) Assert!
         }
         std::cout << "printed resultset" << std::endl;

         stmt->closeResultSet(res);
         con->terminateStatement(stmt);
        environment->terminateConnection(con);

     }catch(oracle::occi::SQLException &e){
         std::cout<<e.what();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you linked to the debug versions of Oracle DLLs (`oraocci11d.lib` and `oraocci11d.dll`)?

It seems that your program uses the memory debugging option of Visual Studio while the Oracle DLLs you're using don't. So the error occurs because the run-time library thinks there's a memory allocation/deallocation problem.

Answer (score 2):

What compiler are you using?

Make sure to download properly occi version
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/occidownloads-083553.html

You must use DLL runtime:

- DLL multithread Debug (/MDd) for debug with oraocci11d.lib and oraocci11d.dll
- DLL multithread (/MD) for release  with oraocci11.lib and oraocci11.dll

Answer (score 1):

if you DB using UTF8 character set
try using following
Environment *environment = Environment::createEnvironment("AL32UTF8","UTF8");